# Finding words in plural and singular when searching for plural word form in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

I come to you today because I have a little trouble. I am currently working on a csv import and transform the data into an object with models in the database. I send the API an object name and I made a $or for a search with plural or not:

```js
if (req.query.name) {
        params.$or =  [
            {name: { '$regex' : new RegExp(req.query.name+'(?!es|s|x)'), '$options' : 'ig' }},
            {name: { '$regex' : new RegExp(req.query.name), '$options' : 'ig' }},
            ]
    }
```

The problem is that if, for example, I send "boxes" and the model is called "Box (small)", it does not work. however if I send "box", it works. Could you enlighten me on my problem? it comes from the regexp.

EDIT : I would like to find the word "box" even if I send "boxes". Basically find the word whether plural or singular

Thank you in advance !

(Sorry for my English, I'm French)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `(?:es|[sx])` at the end of the search term (you may use `.replace(/(?:es|[sx])$/, '')`) and add an optional group, not a negative lookahead:

```
new RegExp(req.query.name.replace(/(?:es|[sx])$/, '') + '(?:es|[sx])?')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u1fISi/1/).

The `(?!es|s|x)` negative lookahead fails the match if the regex engine finds `es`, `s` or `x` immediately after the `req.query.name` value, while you want to optionally match a part of a string.

Comment: I think I misspoke, I would like to find the word "box" even if I send "boxes". Basically find the word whether plural or singular

Comment: @Lucatorze OK, so the fix is much simpler, use an optional group.

Comment: excuse me, I have a little trouble making myself understood, here is what I would like: https://regex101.com/r/u1fISi/3 (Ignore (small), just box

Comment: Ok, so you want to remove `(?:es|[sx])` before adding an optional group. Then, you will deal with [this case](https://regex101.com/r/u1fISi/4).

Comment: I would like the plural noun match with the singular name Boxes -> box

Comment: `new RegExp(req.query.name.replace(/(?:es|[sx])$/, '') + '(?:es|[sx])?')` will do.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I will adapt to my needs but that's exactly what I'm looking for !!